# Using OpenFeint to get current Achievement progression

Tags: iphone, openfeint, achievements

So I'm setting my achievement like so:

```
int currentPercentage = ... // Work out current percentage of progression to update too
[[OFAchievement achievement: ACHIEVEMENT_ID] updateProgressionComplete: currentPercentage andShowNotification: YES];
```

But is there anyway to get the currentProgression from the OF servers?

This would be useful to know so I can update the progression by a percentage rather than storing values locally to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by calling :

```
[OFAchievementService getPercentComplete:achievementId forUser:[OpenFeint lastLoggedInUserId]];
```

Comment: this function is disappeared and I know no replacement for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following call:

```
double ofAchievementProgress = [[OFAchievement achievement:achievementId] percentComplete];
```