# OpenFeint achievement percentage increment

Tags: iphone, partial, openfeint, achievements

I'm making an iOS app which is OpenFeint enabled.
I have managed to get all but one achievement to work. This one achievement is a partially completed one.

My specific problem is that I haven't found a working solution to add 1% to the current achievement percentage.

I found this value (it's supposed to be a `double`):

```
double achievement12 = [OFAchievementService getPercentComplete:ach12Id 
                                                        forUser:[OpenFeint lastLoggedInUserID]];
```

but this causes the following errors and warnings:

> "Cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'double' in initialization.
>
> 'OpenFeint' may not respond to "+lastLoggedInUserId"
>
> 'OFAchievementService' may not respond to "+getPercentComplete:forUser:"

The actual function code is:

```
    // Note: this should be moved into public API
   + (double) getPercentComplete:(NSString*)achievementId forUser:(NSString*)userId
    {
        sAlreadyAtLeastPartlyCompleteQuery.bind("achievement_definition_id", achievementId);
        sAlreadyAtLeastPartlyCompleteQuery.bind("user_id", userId);     
        sAlreadyAtLeastPartlyCompleteQuery.execute();
        float percentComplete = (double)    (sAlreadyAtLeastPartlyCompleteQuery.getDouble("percent_complete"));
    sAlreadyAtLeastPartlyCompleteQuery.resetQuery();
    return percentComplete;
    }
```

This is the last thing I have to do on this app, and it has been bugging me for a few days now.

Comment: it is an NSString which contains the achievement id for my 12th achievement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenFeint support said that they have not integrated that part due to security issues.

With that said, i have now resorted to storing a file with the data in so i can retrieve it later (using an equation to hide the real value of course)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the `NSSString` achievement id is correct and I think it returns an `int`, not a double.

[Using OpenFeint to get current Achievement progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610481/using-openfeint-to-get-current-achievement-progression)

Comment: the id is correct but it it won't build because of the error, and even if it did, the warnings would still affect it so it wouldn't work

Comment: i have found the function in one of the OpenFeint files called OFAchievementService+private.mm and have included it in my question.

Comment: What version of OpenFeint are you using? Last time I used it, int worked fine.

Comment: According to the console i am using OpenFeint version 3072011 (2.9.1)

Comment: I almost forgot, when i put "int" instead of "double" i get a different error to "Cannot convert 'objc_object*' to 'double' in initialization.". Instead i get "Invalid conversion from 'objc_object' to 'int'"